# Tools to convert joomla and wordpress template to Drupal 7 theme?

Tags: joomla, drupal, template, file-conversion

Is there any tool to convert joomla and wordpress  template to Drupal 7 theme?

Answer (score 3):

Artisteer is not good enough. You cannot get the original look. It is better to manually convert the theme.

1. Take any Drupal 7 framework like Zen and Genesis
2. Style the CSS using the Joomla/WordPress style sheet.
3. Use the same design elements that are used in the old theme.
4. Use some Modules like Views and Panels to get the teasers on the front page.

If you are not good enough on coding go to some Freelance web designers to do the job.

Answer (score 1):

Check out http://www.artisteer.com/. This tool may help you out.